# SOAP Server-Push with TomCat, CXF, Atmosphere over Websockets

Tags: java, tomcat, soap, cxf, atmosphere

My application needs to send and receive SOAP messages using WebSockets.
Most of the time the client (written in Python) talks to the server (Java) in a simple Request-Response pattern which is already working.

Sometimes, if a client updates some data in the centralized database managed by the server, all other clients should be notified with the updated data or any other kind of notifcation that something happend (Broadcast)

My current stack consists of the following technologies:

- Server written in Java
- Client written in Python 3.4
- Tomcat 8.5.12
- Apache CXF 3.1.10
- Atmosphere 2.4.9

The stack can be changed, except for the following:

- The languages the server and client are written in
- The messages transferred need to be SOAP
- Tomcat as the servlet manager
- WebSockets can be changed to Long-Polling only if it's not possible otherwise.

Talking to the server in a Request-Response pattern is already working.
However, I don't know how to get the server push working.
I already played around with @WebSocketProcessorService, @ManagedService, @AtmosphereResourceListenerService which are listed within the Atmosphere Wiki.
But either I have access to the plain message itself but no automatic SOAP handling, or the other way around.
Using annotations like @Broadcast did not have any effect within sample.ServerEndpoint.
All examples found on the Wiki or other Blogs are only working on plain WebSockets which handle the messages itself and returning plain Strings.

I would really be thankfull for an example with the following features:

- One service method working in a simple Request-Response Pattern (like below, already working)
- One service method which returns a normal Reponse but also starts a broadcast to all clients (in - or excluding the one calling the method) on a condition (e.g. an update to a variable was successfull or not)

My current status:

web.xml (Server)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
  <description>AtmosphereServlet</description>
  <display-name>AtmosphereServlet</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <description>AtmosphereServlet</description>
    <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet</servlet-class>
    <!-- If you want to use Servlet 3.0 -->
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

atmosphere.xml (Server)

```
<atmosphere-handlers>
    <atmosphere-handler support-session="false"
                    context-root="/*"
                    class-name="org.atmosphere.handler.ReflectorServletProcessor">
        <property name="servletClassName"
              value="sample.ServerServlet"/>
    </atmosphere-handler>
</atmosphere-handlers>
```

sample.ServerServlet.java (Server)

```
package sample;

import org.apache.cxf.Bus;
import org.apache.cxf.BusFactory;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class ServerServlet extends org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void loadBus(ServletConfig servletConfig) {
        super.loadBus(servletConfig);
        Bus bus = getBus();
        BusFactory.setDefaultBus(bus);
        Endpoint.publish("/GreetingService", new ServerEndpoint());
    }
}
```

sample.ServerEndpoint.java (Server)

```
package sample;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.xml.ws.ResponseWrapper;

@WebService(name="GreetingService",
    targetNamespace="http://sample",
    wsdlLocation="file:///data/projects/apache-cfx/build/service.wsdl",
    serviceName="GreetingService")
@SOAPBinding(style=SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public class ServerEndpoint {
    @ResponseWrapper(targetNamespace="http://sample/types",
                     className="java.lang.String")
    @WebMethod(action = "getQuote")
    public String getQuote(@WebParam(name="ticker") String ticker,
                           @WebParam(name="name") String name) {
        return "foobar! " + ticker + " - " + name;
    }
}
```